# reducing number of plot ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, yticks

I have too many ticks on my graph and they are running into each other.

How can I reduce the number of ticks?

For example, I have ticks:

```
1E-6, 1E-5, 1E-4, ... 1E6, 1E7
```

And I only want:

```
1E-5, 1E-3, ... 1E5, 1E7
```

I've tried playing with the `LogLocator`, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to simply set the number of ticks while allowing matplotlib to position them (currently only with `MaxNLocator`), there is [`pyplot.locator_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.locator_params),

```
pyplot.locator_params(nbins=4)
```

You can specify specific axis in this method as mentioned below, default is both:

```
# To specify the number of ticks on both or any single axes
pyplot.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=6)
pyplot.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=10)
```

Comment: This was a great suggestion, also being able to specify `pyplot.locator_params(axis = 'x', nbins = 4)` (or `axis = 'y'`) made the process really straightforward.  Thanks @bgamari!

Comment: Is there any way I could use that with a FixedLocator?

Comment: how to use the MaxNLocator instead of FixedLocator?

Comment: With log scale, this worked with ``numticks`` instead of ``nbins``

Comment: @bgamari, could you please add the `numticks` solution for logarithmic plots as pointed out by @meduz?

Comment: How does this function work, how do you have to use it? I used `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.locator_params(axis='x', nticks=4)` before and after `plt.plot` but it does nothing. I use version `2.1.1`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to place the labels where they should be. For example, if the original tick labels are `[0, 1, ..., 99]` and now one sets `nticks=10`, then the new sparse labels will be placed ten times as long apart along the axis, i.e. now `1` will sit where `9` was, `2` where `19` was... and `9` where `99` was.

Comment: Check your results before trusting this method. @Vim is correct. The tick values will be placed incorrectly.

Comment: Adding to @mikkokotila comment about future version incompatibility. You can use the `set_major_locator`, see full answer below

Comment: This is very straightforward. I could also use it on an existing `matplotlib.axes.Axes` (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params.html)

Comment: I got incorrect labeling with this method, but @Katerina's worked as expected.

Comment: I have been looking for how to plot timeseries data without weekend gaps and this code helped me to format the xticks nicely.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 133):

To solve the issue of customisation and appearance of the ticks, see the [Tick Locators](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) guide on the matplotlib website

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
```

would set the total number of ticks in the x-axis to 3, and evenly distribute them across the axis.

There is also a [nice tutorial about this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html)

Comment: Only select first 3 datetime index. when get ax from pandas.DataFrame.plot   `ax = df.plot()`

Comment: @Mithril sorry I don't quite understand your comment. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If I have a df ( `pandas.DataFrame` ) with datetime index  [2019-01-01, ...2019-11-01], call  `ax = df.plot()` ,  return a figure object  . call `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))`  only show first 3 index   [2019-01-01,  2019-01-02, 2019-01-03] .

Comment: @Mithril, `df.plot()` often displays the `minor_locator`, so you might want to try `ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))`. Also remember to substitute the `3` for the number of ticks that you want to display. For pandas timeseries I recommend  `import matplotlib.dates as mdates` and run `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval = 1))` with `ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%Y'))`

Comment: As I had a lot of datapoints to plot, pyplot was printing a lot (>500) ticks per axis. This heavily slowed down the plotting process. By reducing the number of thicks with `set_major_locator(5)` the plotting process is much faster.

Comment: Another wonderful solution

Answer (score 108):

If somebody still gets this page in search results:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(...)

every_nth = 4
for n, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: In my case with pandas and numerically spaced, this is working as is expected while locator_params(nbins) and plt.MaxNLocator give a strange behavior.

Comment: This works for non-numerical x axis labels, which is helpful

Answer (score 27):

There's a [`set_ticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticks.html) function for axis objects.

Comment: This would work if I knew beforehand what ticks I wanted. The example I gave above was only an example. I don't know what the ticks are, I just know I want fewer of them, i.e., every other one.

Comment: You could call `get_xticks()` or `get_yticks()` first for the axes object, edit as needed, and then pass the list back to `set_ticks()`.

Comment: I don't have `set_ticks()`, but I do have `set_xticks()` and `set_yticks()`. These are attributes of axes objects, not axis. Maybe this has changed during the last couple of years.

Comment: I am not sure if I should, some people have found your answer useful as is, and just because it is different for me does not mean it is for everybody.

Comment: An example would go a long way towards making this answer useful.

Answer (score 14):

in case somebody still needs it, and since nothing 
here really worked for me, i came up with a very 
simple way that keeps the appearance of the 
generated plot "as is" while fixing the number 
of ticks to exactly N:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(100))

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_yticks(np.round(np.linspace(ymin, ymax, N), 2))
```

Comment: I had to modify the last line slightly in order to get it to return the values as int instead of float: `ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(int(ymin), int(ymax), N), 2)`

Comment: @NickSettje still floats with me!

Answer (score 9):

The solution @raphael gave is straightforward and quite helpful.

Still, the displayed tick labels will not be values sampled from the original distribution but from the *indices* of the array returned by `np.linspace(ymin, ymax, N)`.

To display N values evenly spaced from your original tick labels, use the `set_yticklabels()` method. Here is a snippet for the y axis, with integer labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
custom_ticks = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, N, dtype=int)
ax.set_yticks(custom_ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(custom_ticks)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need one tick every N=3 ticks :

```
N = 3  # 1 tick every 3
xticks_pos, xticks_labels = plt.xticks()  # get all axis ticks
myticks = [j for i,j in enumerate(xticks_pos) if not i%N]  # index of selected ticks
newlabels = [label for i,label in enumerate(xticks_labels) if not i%N]
```

or with `fig,ax = plt.subplots()` :

```
N = 3  # 1 tick every 3
xticks_pos = ax.get_xticks()
xticks_labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
myticks = [j for i,j in enumerate(xticks_pos) if not i%N]  # index of selected ticks
newlabels = [label for i,label in enumerate(xticks_labels) if not i%N]
```

(obviously you can adjust the offset with `(i+offset)%N`).

Note that you can get uneven ticks if you wish, e.g. `myticks = [1, 3, 8]`.

Then you can use

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(myticks)  # set new X axis ticks
```

or if you want to replace labels as well

```
plt.xticks(myticks, newlabels)  # set new X axis ticks and labels
```

Beware that axis limits must be set **after** the axis ticks.

Finally, you may wish to draw only an **arbitrary** set of ticks :

```
mylabels = ['03/2018', '09/2019', '10/2020']
plt.draw()  # needed to populate xticks with actual labels
xticks_pos, xticks_labels = plt.xticks()  # get all axis ticks
myticks = [i for i,j in enumerate(xticks_labels) if j.get_text() in mylabels]
plt.xticks(myticks, mylabels)
```

(assuming `mylabels` is ordered ; if it is not, then sort `myticks` and reorder it).

Comment: there is a little error in the last code block. One of the lines should be written as:
`myticks = [i for i,j in enumerate(xticks_labels) if j.get_text() in mylabels]`

Comment: @gtristan Right, fixed, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

xticks function auto iterates with range function

start_number = 0

end_number = len(data you have)

step_number = how many skips to make from strat to end

rotation = 90 degrees tilt will help with long ticks

```
plt.xticks(range(start_number,end_number,step_number),rotation=90)
```

Comment: I came to contribute a range based solution. Your example is much more concise. But to add to it, you can use the shape to get what you want eg `plt.xticks(range(0, df.shape[0], 12),rotation=90)`

Answer (score 3):

if you want 10 ticks:

for y axis: `ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[::len(ax.get_yticks())//10])`

for x axis: `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::len(ax.get_xticks())//10])`

this simply gets your ticks and chooses every 10th of the list and sets it back to your ticks. you can change the number of ticks as you wish.

Answer (score -2):

When a log scale is used the number of major ticks can be fixed with the following command

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

....

plt.locator_params(numticks=12)
plt.show()
```

The value set to `numticks` determines the number of axis ticks to be displayed.

Credits to @bgamari's post for introducing the `locator_params()` function, but the `nticks` parameter throws an error when a log scale is used.

Comment: The question and answer are for previous matplotlib, i.e. 1, and you're referring to 2.

Comment: I do not think an argument called 'numticks' exists.

Comment: Kindly refer the [matplotlib doc for numticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/search.html?q=Numticks) @troymyname00