# Changing the tick frequency on the x or y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, xticks, yticks

I am trying to fix how python plots my data. Say:

```py
x = [0, 5, 9, 10, 15]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

The x axis' ticks are plotted in intervals of 5. Is there a way to make it show intervals of 1?

Comment: Closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/how-to-reduce-number-of-ticks-with-matplotlib and a great solution: `pyplot.locator_params(nbins=4)`

Answer (score 911, accepted):

You could explicitly set where you want to tick marks with `plt.xticks`:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
plt.show()
```

---

(`np.arange` was used rather than Python's `range` function just in case `min(x)` and `max(x)` are floats instead of ints.)

---

The `plt.plot` (or `ax.plot`) function will automatically set default `x` and `y` limits. If you wish to keep those limits, and just change the stepsize of the tick marks, then you could use `ax.get_xlim()` to discover what limits Matplotlib has already set.

```
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, stepsize))
```

The default tick formatter should do a decent job rounding the tick values to a sensible number of significant digits. However, if you wish to have more control over the format, you can define your own formatter. For example,

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
```

Here's a runnable example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, 0.712123))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there no way to get it to still decide it's own limits, but just change the step size?  This method is not very good if the min is something like 3523.232512!

Comment: @Corone, It has been a while since you asked, but I have posted an answer below that allows for easy control of step size while still using automatic bounds determination.

Comment: Note that the `+1` in `plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))` is required to show the last tick mark.

Comment: Yes, `np.arange(start, stop)` generates values in the *half-open* interval `[start, stop)`, including `start` but excluding `stop`. So I used `max(x)+1` to ensure that `max(x)` is included.

Comment: is there an equivalent for datetime e.g.  ```plt.xticks(np.arange(min(dates), max(dates)+0.1,0.1)``` ? it seems to only plots the year

Comment: @WBM: You can set both the location and labels using [`xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). Alternatively, you could use [FuncFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html) to convert floats to string labels. Or if you plot `datetime.datetime` objects directly (instead of floats) then you could use [DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html) to format the dates. If this doesn't help or you'd like more clarification, please post a new question.

Comment: @unutbu when I run your code I get `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` ...any idea ?  -- I am on matplotlib 2.2.3

Comment: it somehow doesnt work when the format of x axis is datetime.

Comment: Nice answer. What is the reason for using `np.arange()`? I seem to be able to do this with a simple list `ax.xaxis.set_ticks(list(range(...)))`, without `numpy`. Thanks.

Comment: Way too complicated. Use ticker.MultipleLocator.

Answer (score 300):

Another approach is to set the axis locator:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0) # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```

There are several different types of locator depending upon your needs.

Here is a full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0) # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. Specifically, when using dates, it does not use the appropriate dates.

Comment: When using dates, you should use the methods in the matplotlib.dates module. For example `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator()`

Comment: It worked as expected for me, with dates. This solution is much easier than the accepted one.

Comment: What does `base=1.0` actually mean/do ?

Comment: base=1.0 means that there will a locator for every whole number. The documentation says that MultipleLocator "Set[s] a tick on each integer multiple of a base within the view interval.". So if base=2 then there'll be a tick for even numbers and I think that you could event put base=2.5.

Comment: This worked for me using floats as well (e.g. 0.1), which is useful for creating graphs in which the y axis lies between 0 and 1.

Comment: `matplotlib.ticker` doesn't need to be imported explicitly. `plt.MultipleLocator` works just fine.

Answer (score 200):

I like this solution (from the [Matplotlib Plotting Cookbook](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/matplotlib-plotting-cookbook/9781849513265/ch03s11.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]

tick_spacing = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
plt.show()
```

This solution give you explicit control of the tick spacing via the number given to `ticker.MultipleLocater()`, allows automatic limit determination, and is easy to read later.

Comment: A way to do this without calculating the ticks explicitly!

Comment: This is the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972993/4124317). It does not make sense to add an identical answer two years later.

Comment: Good catch. I did not recognize them as the same when I posted the answer. Still, I think this presentation is a little easier to understand.

Comment: The book reference in this answer also provide a helpful source for more information.

Comment: This is the same answer as that of robochat, which came three years earlier.

Comment: @MERose, you are correct. Please see comments above for justification on including this answer.

Comment: Please keep this answer, it is more readable than the other one

Comment: For future reference, instead of writing a new answer with the same solution, simply edit the other one to be more clear. I also find yours much more clear.

Comment: For log scale, use e.g. `ticker.LogLocator(base=2, numticks=3)`.

Answer (score 160):

In case anyone is interested in a general one-liner, simply get the current ticks and use it to set the new ticks by sampling every other tick.

```
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

Comment: This is the only generalisable answer for different tick types (str, float, datetime)

Comment: Remove non-integer ticks:  


`ax.set_xticks([tick for tick in ax.get_xticks() if tick % 1 == 0])`

Comment: Lots of detailed solutions above but I agree this is the most concise. You could even extract the length of ax.get_xticks() and set the slicing frequency by this length divided by the number of required ticks.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Most other answers are too complicated and hard to apply/generalize. Thank you!

Comment: It can only reduce number of sticks, whereas in the question (and mine goal how I found it) was to increase it.

Comment: If you want to change tick label frequency as well but got an error, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76368556/19123103) for a solution.

Comment: To address @AlexMartian's point a one-liner to double the frequency of ticks would be quite convoluted: `ax.set_xticks( [* range(int(ax.get_xticks()[0]), int(ax.get_xticks()[-1])+1, int( (ax.get_xticks()[-1] - ax.get_xticks()[0])/(len(ax.get_xticks())-1) / 2 )) ] )`

Answer (score 56):

if you just want to set the spacing a simple one liner with minimal boilerplate:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
```

also works easily for minor ticks:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
```

a bit of a mouthfull, but pretty compact

Comment: Worth mentioning the argument ``plt.MultipleLocator(arg)`` is the tick interval. So, if you want your ticks to be 5 units away from each other, just use ``plt.MultipleLocator(5)``. Otherwise like this solution the most. Thank you!

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(val))` in case you are using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Answer (score 40):

This is a bit hacky, but by far the cleanest/easiest to understand example that I've found to do this. It's from an answer on SO here:

[Cleanest way to hide every nth tick label in matplotlib colorbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337664/cleanest-way-to-hide-every-nth-tick-label-in-matplotlib-colorbar)

```
for label in ax.get_xticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Then you can loop over the labels setting them to visible or not depending on the density you want.

edit: note that sometimes matplotlib sets labels == `''`, so it might look like a label is not present, when in fact it is and just isn't displaying anything. To make sure you're looping through actual visible labels, you could try:

```
visible_labels = [lab for lab in ax.get_xticklabels() if lab.get_visible() is True and lab.get_text() != '']
plt.setp(visible_labels[::2], visible=False)
```

Comment: This is the most simple and generic solution. A tiny adjustment: usually `ax.get_xticklabels()[1::2]` are the labels to be hidden.

Comment: This doesn't work with matplotlib.finance.candlestick2

Comment: @BCR it could be that some of the xticklabels are just set to `''` so that when you loop through them, you're making xticklabels that are empty invisible (which would have no effect on the visualization, but might mean that you aren't pulling the correct labels). You could try:

`vis_labels = [label for label in ax.get_xticklabels() if label.get_visible() is True]; plt.setp(vis_labels[::2], visible==False)`

Answer (score 19):

This is an old topic, but I stumble over this every now and then and made this function. It's very convenient:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np

def resadjust(ax, xres=None, yres=None):
    """
    Send in an axis and I fix the resolution as desired.
    """

    if xres:
        start, stop = ax.get_xlim()
        ticks = np.arange(start, stop + xres, xres)
        ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    if yres:
        start, stop = ax.get_ylim()
        ticks = np.arange(start, stop + yres, yres)
        ax.set_yticks(ticks)
```

One caveat of controlling the ticks like this is that one does no longer enjoy the interactive automagic updating of max scale after an added line. Then do

```
gca().set_ylim(top=new_top) # for example
```

and run the resadjust function again.

Answer (score 13):

I developed an inelegant solution. Consider that we have the X axis and also a list of labels for each point in X.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,20,15,18,7,19]
xlabels = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun']
```

Let's say that I want to show ticks labels only for 'feb' and 'jun'

```
xlabelsnew = []
for i in xlabels:
    if i not in ['feb','jun']:
        i = ' '
        xlabelsnew.append(i)
    else:
        xlabelsnew.append(i)
```

Good, now we have a fake list of labels. First, we plotted the original version.

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(range(0,len(x)),xlabels,rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Now, the modified version.

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(range(0,len(x)),xlabelsnew,rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

Generalisable one liner, with only Numpy imported:

```py
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x),max(x),1))
```

Set in the context of the question:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x),max(x),1))
plt.show()
```

How it works:

1. `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` gives the ax object which contains the axes.
2. `np.arange(min(x),max(x),1)` gives an array of interval 1 from the min of x to the max of x. This is the new x ticks that we want.
3. `ax.set_xticks()` changes the ticks on the ax object.

Comment: so, can you explain the code?

Comment: I've rewritten it to make it clearer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 9):

## Pure Python Implementation

Below's a pure python implementation of the desired functionality that handles any numeric series (int or float) with positive, negative, or mixed values and allows for the user to specify the desired step size:

```
import math

def computeTicks (x, step = 5):
    """
    Computes domain with given step encompassing series x
    @ params
    x    - Required - A list-like object of integers or floats
    step - Optional - Tick frequency
    """
    xMax, xMin = math.ceil(max(x)), math.floor(min(x))
    dMax, dMin = xMax + abs((xMax % step) - step) + (step if (xMax % step != 0) else 0), xMin - abs((xMin % step))
    return range(dMin, dMax, step)
```

## Sample Output

```
# Negative to Positive
series = [-2, 18, 24, 29, 43]
print(list(computeTicks(series)))

[-5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]

# Negative to 0
series = [-30, -14, -10, -9, -3, 0]
print(list(computeTicks(series)))

[-30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0]

# 0 to Positive
series = [19, 23, 24, 27]
print(list(computeTicks(series)))

[15, 20, 25, 30]

# Floats
series = [1.8, 12.0, 21.2]
print(list(computeTicks(series)))

[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

# Step – 100
series = [118.3, 293.2, 768.1]
print(list(computeTicks(series, step = 100)))

[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
```

## Sample Usage

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(computeTicks(x))
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of sample usage]

Notice the x-axis has integer values all evenly spaced by 5, whereas the y-axis has a different interval (the `matplotlib` default behavior, because the ticks weren't specified).

Answer (score 6):

```
xmarks=[i for i in range(1,length+1,1)]

plt.xticks(xmarks)
```

This worked for me

if you want ticks between [1,5] (1 and 5 inclusive) then replace

```
length = 5
```

Comment: fyi, you could simply write `xmarks = range(1, length+1, 1)`. pretty sure the list comprehension is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

Since **None** of the above solutions worked for my usecase, here I provide a solution using `None` (pun!) which can be adapted to a wide variety of scenarios.

Here is a sample piece of code that produces cluttered ticks on both `X` and `Y` axes.

```
# Note the super cluttered ticks on both X and Y axis.

# inputs
x = np.arange(1, 101)
y = x * np.log(x) 

fig = plt.figure()     # create figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xticks(x)        # set xtick values
ax.set_yticks(y)        # set ytick values

plt.show()
```

Now, we clean up the clutter with a new plot that shows only a sparse set of values on both x and y axes as ticks.

```
# inputs
x = np.arange(1, 101)
y = x * np.log(x)

fig = plt.figure()       # create figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_yticks(y)

# which values need to be shown?
# here, we show every third value from `x` and `y`
show_every = 3

sparse_xticks = [None] * x.shape[0]
sparse_xticks[::show_every] = x[::show_every]

sparse_yticks = [None] * y.shape[0]
sparse_yticks[::show_every] = y[::show_every]

ax.set_xticklabels(sparse_xticks, fontsize=6)   # set sparse xtick values
ax.set_yticklabels(sparse_yticks, fontsize=6)   # set sparse ytick values

plt.show()
```

Depending on the usecase, one can adapt the above code simply by changing `show_every` and using that for sampling tick values for X or Y or both the axes.

If this stepsize based solution doesn't fit, then one can also populate the values of `sparse_xticks` or `sparse_yticks` at irregular intervals, if that is what is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Setting big & small ticks together:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5)) # set BIG ticks
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1)) # set small ticks

x = range(0,21)
y = [4,8,3,10,6,12,5] * 3

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through labels and show or hide those you want:

```
   for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels()):
        if i % interval != 0:
            label.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the ticklabel frequency along with tick frequency using the old ticklabels, using `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` one after the other throws a ValueError that looks like the following:

```
ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (5), usually from 
a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of labels (3).
```

A way get around the issue is to use `set()` method to set the two simultaneously. An example may illustrate it better.

```py
import pandas as pd
ax = pd.Series(range(20), index=pd.date_range('2020', '2024', 20).date).plot()
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])             # <---- error   
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels()[::2]);  # <---- error


ax = pd.Series(range(20), index=pd.date_range('2020', '2024', 20).date).plot()
ax.set(xticks=ax.get_xticks()[::2], 
       xticklabels=ax.get_xticklabels()[::2]);  # <---- OK
```

[image: result]

---

<sup>For this specific case, `matplotlib.dates.YearLocator` and `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter` is more flexible (e.g. `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())`) and is probably the preferred way to set ticklabels but the post above offers a quick fix for a common error.</sup>