# imshow plots with integer axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using the labels on axis of an `imshow` plot as labels for different tests and therefore I want these labels to be real. However I am getting float numbers e.g. 3.5 ,3.0. How can I change this?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=np.random.randn(4,4)
plt.imshow(a,extent=[1,5,1,5],interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Just use an integer array to set the ticks:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 6, dtype=np.int))
```