# Keep Constant Tick Spacing in a scrolling MATPLOTLIB chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm hoping that this can be answered without having to supply some code, as there are over a thousand lines and I'm not sure where the problem is.

Basically, I've created a charting class that that scrolls and updates the data as it comes in in real time. There are loads of features such as multiple y-axes, ability to pause, add vertical value lines etc etc, hence the many LOC. Nearly everything is working quite well.

I achieve the scrolling by grabbing the background then resetting and blitting when new data comes in. I have separate subcharts for each line (for the multiple y-axes) and reset the limits and call draw_artist on the main subplot only fr the x and y axes.

The problem is that as the data scrolls, depending on the current aspect, the x axis tick marks can keep changing their spacing each time new data comes in. So it might look like: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12 in one instant and then 0,5,10 the next.

Comment: I'm thinking of using one of the solutions described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib?rq=1

The answer suggesting ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))

Comment: When you redraw you can take care, among all the other stuff, of explicitly setting the x axis limits and the x axis ticks.

Comment: I think that might be the problem, in that I'm letting MATPLOTLIB do this automatically and it appears to use more than just the range when calculating the tick spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got a solution to this. When new data comes in I call the following code:

```
if self.tickSpacing is not None:
    self.MPLsubPlot.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(self.tickSpacing))
else:
    self.MPLsubPlot.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
```

self.tickSpacing is initialised to None and set to None when the user starts a pan/zoom on mouse down. On mouse up (once the pan/zoom is complete) the following function is called:

```
def _updateSpacing(self):
    labels = self.MPLsubPlot.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
    if len(labels) > 1:
        self.tickSpacing = labels[1] - labels[0]
```

This allows matplotlib to automatically determine the spacing on initial or changed aspect and then explicitly use that value on update on new data.