# Choose matplotlib xticks frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting data with strings as x labels. I'd like to control the label frequency to not overload the axis with text. In the example below i'd like to only see a label every 3 tick: a-d-g-j.

[image]

One way I could do that is to replace the my_xticks elements by 2 empty strings every n elements. 
But i'm sure it gives a cleaner way to do that.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=np.array([4,4,4,5,5,6,5,5,4,4,4])
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
my_xticks=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']

plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're almost there! Sample the first and second arguments of xticks at the desired frequency!

The question is a duplicate from [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([4,4,4,5,5,6,5,5,4,4,4])
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
my_xticks = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'])
frequency = 3
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x[::frequency], my_xticks[::frequency])
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thx for answer. Instead of having to specify the targeted letters, i'd rather just give a period number so that the method can be used with a high numer of labels. I am currently trying to understand the duplicate post you mentioned.

Comment: well from my understanding it's not really a duplicate because in the post they use an array of numbers as ticks whereas I am dealing with strings.

Comment: I understand your question now. See the updated answer.

Comment: what if I want to tick on a particular alphabets?

Comment: change the variable my_xticks to the alphabet you want.