# tick frequency when using seaborn/matplotlib boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, ticker

I am plotting with seaborn a series of boxplots with

```py
sns.boxplot(full_array)
```

where `full_array` contains 200 arrays. Therefore, I have 200 boxplots and ticks on the x-axis from 0 to 200.

The xticks are too close to each other and I would like to show only some of them, for instance, a labeled xtick every 20, or so.

I tried several solutions as those mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) but they did not work.

Every time I sample the xticks, I get wrong labels for the ticks, as they get numbered from 0 to N, with unit spacing.

For instance, with the line

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
```

I get a labelled xtick every 20 but the labels are 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 20, 40, 60, 80...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The seaborn boxplot uses a FixedLocator and a FixedFormatter, i.e.

```
print ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()
print ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter()
```

prints

```
<matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator object at 0x000000001FE0D668>
<matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter object at 0x000000001FD67B00>
```

It's therefore not sufficient to set the locator to a `MultipleLocator` since the ticks' values would still be set by the fixed formatter.

Instead you would want to set a `ScalarFormatter`, which sets the ticklabels to correspond to the numbers at their position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import numpy as np

ax = sns.boxplot(data = np.random.rand(20,30))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of seaborn (v.0.12.0 etc.), the ticks' values are set by `FuncFormatter`, so OP's initial attempt works fine.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

data = np.random.rand(20,30)
ax = sns.boxplot(data=data)

ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()                    # <matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator at 0x2221f657340>
ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter()                  # <matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter at 0x2221f8e2a00>

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))  # show every 5th tick
```

Another way that works is to simply set the xticks by selecting every 5th.

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(data=data);
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::5]);            # show every 5th tick
```

[image: result]