# Plotting more than 10K data point using Seaborn for x-axis as timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot more than 10k data points, where I want to plot a data properties versus Timestamp. But on the x-axis the timestamps are overlapping and not visible.

How can I reduce the amount of labels on the x-axis, so that they are legible?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

data = pd.read_csv('0912Testday4.csv',header=2)

for i in data.columns:
    if i!='TIMESTAMP':
        sns.lineplot(x="TIMESTAMP",y=i,data = data)
        plt.title(f"{i} vs TIMESTAMP")
        plt.show()
```

Example plot demonstrating the problem:

[image: Example plot demonstrating the problem]

Update:**TIMESTAMP** was in string format by converting into **datatime** format it resolves the problem.

```
data['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIMESTAMP'])
```

Comment: 10k labels wouldn't be visible even if the labels are rotated by 90 degrees, maybe plot after aggregating over a year or a month?

Comment: i just wanted to show few labels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tick frequency when using seaborn/matplotlib boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521648/tick-frequency-when-using-seaborn-matplotlib-boxplot)

Answer (score 1):

Update:TIMESTAMP was in string format by converting into datetime format it resolves the problem.

```
data['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIMESTAMP'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `TIMESTAMP` is a datetime object. This should not happen when the x axis is a datetime. (You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert int, float, str, and ... to datetime.)

If `TIMESTAMP` is a datetime, you can use the `autofmt_xdate()` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # Create a figure and a set of subplots.

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

data = pd.read_csv('0912Testday4.csv',header=2)

# Use the following line if the TIMESTAMP is not a datetime.
# (You may need to change the format from "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00".)
# data['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(data.TIMESTAMP, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00")

for i in data.columns:
    if i!='TIMESTAMP':
        sns.lineplot(x="TIMESTAMP", y=i, data=data, ax=ax)
        fig.autofmt_xdate() # rotate and right align date ticklabels
        plt.title(f"{i} vs TIMESTAMP")
        plt.show()
```

Comment: The example format above converts a string like "2020-07-19 12:17:54+00:00" to a datetime. The actual format depends on your `TIMESTAMP` values.

Comment: By converting it to datatime formate resolves the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't encounter such problem with `sns.lineplot`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

# example data
time_stamps = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', freq='H')
vals =[np.random.randint(0, 1000) for i in time_stamps]
data_df = pd.DataFrame()
data_df['time'] = time_stamps
data_df['value'] = vals
print(data_df.shape)

# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='value', data=data_df)


plt.show()
```

sns automatically selects the x ticks and x labels.

alternatively, you can use `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xlabels` to set the x ticks and x labels manually.
Also you may use fig.autofmt_xdate() to rotate the x labels