# Setting the distance between axis labels with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn to plot a distribution using `sns.distplot(x)` and am having some issues with overriding the default distance between axis labels. Here is the plot

[image]

The issue I have is that along the x axis, I would rather have each integer and not a float spaced 2.5 apart.

I have been having a look online and havent found anything that explains how to do this.

Edited:
Given that Seaborn is built upon matplotlib, I want to know how the 2 interact. How do I take this chart that is created using Seaborn and use matplotlib to edit it? Then how do I use matplotlib to change these axis to those I am looking for?

Comment: Why has this been down-voted???

Comment: This is a `matplotlib` issue, not a `seaborn` issue. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229671/5285918 Note you'll have to return the matplotlib axis you're plotting on, something like `ax = sns.distplot(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib and merely extends its functionality. It should be thought of as complimentary to matplotlib and not a replacement for it. A more detailed explanation of Seaborn and what it does can be found here:

http://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html

A good answer to this question however can be found here

[stackoverflow.com/a/36229671/5285918](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36229671/5285918)