# Matplotlib: how to set only min and max values for tics

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axis

I have pretty similar code to plot:

```
plt.plot(df_tags[df_tags.detailed_tag == tag]['week'], df_tags[df_tags.detailed_tag == tag].tonality)
```

Output:
[image]

But I want leave only min and max values for x axis this way:

```
plt.plot(df_tags[df_tags.detailed_tag == tag]['week'], df_tags[df_tags.detailed_tag == tag].tonality)
plt.xticks([df_tags['week'].min(), df_tags['week'].max()])
print (df_tags['week'].min(), df_tags['week'].max())
```

With no luck, he puts second week as a last one, but why and how to fix it:
[image]

Comment: Can you please include your small data frame, so people can use it for their tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't be answered with certainty due to the unknown input data. Interpreting the small amount of code that *is* shown one would go for setting the ticks *and* labels,

```
t = [df_tags['week'].min(), df_tags['week'].max()]
plt.xticks(t,t)
```

---

To explain why `plt.xticks(t)` alone does not work:
The inital plot's axis has some tick locations and ticklabels set, i.e. tick locations corresponding to `[2018-03, 2018-04, 2018-05,...]` and the respective ticklabels `[2018-03, 2018-04, 2018-05,...]`. If you now only change the tick locations via `plt.xticks([2018-03, 2018-08])`, the plot will only have two differing tick locations, but still the same labels to occupy those locations. Hence the second label `2018-04` will occupy the second (and last) position.
Since this is undesired, you should always set the tick positions **and** the ticklabels. This is done via `plt.xticks(ticklocations, ticklabels)` or `ax.set_xticks(ticklocations); ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)`.

Comment: Thank that worked, but why `plt.xticks(t)`  didn't work?

Comment: I updated the answer text with some explanation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This hacky solution piggybacks on this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'week': ['2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04', '2018-05', '2018-06', '2018-07', '2018-08'], 'val': np.arange(8)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(df['week'], df['val'])
for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels()):
    if i > 0 and i < len(ax.get_xticklabels()) - 1:
        label.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]