# How to adjust 'tick frequency' for string x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list to draw. Is there a way to display parts of x-axis labels, for example `x[0], x[10], ...`, but keep the figure the same?

```
x = ['alice', 'bob', ...] # string list, len > 100
y = [23, 323, ...] # int list
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: After rotate 90 degree]

Edit 1: There are some other questions like [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) dealing with int label. But doesn't work for me.

Edit 2: Rotating x-axis labels can not help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way you can do this is to reduce the number of ticks on the x axis. You can set the ticks using `ax.set_xticks()`. Here you can slice the `x` list to set a ticks at every 2nd entry using the slice notation `[::2]`. Then set the x tick labels using `ax.set_xticklabels()` using the same slice when setting the ticks.

For example:

```
x = ["Ant", "Bob", "Crab", "Donkey", "Elephant", "Fire", "Giant","Hello",
     "Igloo", "Jump", "Kellogg","Llama", "More", "Night"]
y = np.random.randint(0,10,14)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(9,5))
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_title("Crowded x axis")

ax2.plot(x,y)
ax2.set_xticks(x[::2])
ax2.set_xticklabels(x[::2], rotation=45)
ax2.set_title("Every 2nd ticks on x axis")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's awesome. But there is one problem, in x-radis it displays Ant, Bob and Crab(x[0], x[1], x[2]). Should it display Ant, Donkey and Gaint(x[0], x[3], x[6])?

Comment: @JoeLu I've updated the answer (I had to set the ticks _and_ the tick labels). See if that helps?

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly you mention reducing the number of ticks displayed. There are multiple ways to do this depending on your plot, for example:

**Code Example**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
    14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]

y = [1, 4, 9, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 
     4, 6, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 9, 6, 2, 4, 
     5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3]

labels = ["Ant", "Bob", "Crab", "Donkey", "Elephant", "Fire", "Giant","Hello",
          "Igloo", "Jump", "Bull","Even", "More", "Words", "other", "Bazboo", 
          "Ant", "Bob", "Crab", "Donkey", "Hippo", "Fire", "Giant","Hello",
          "Igloo", "Hump", "Kellogg","Even", "More", "Words", "Piano", "Foobar"]

plt.xticks(x, labels[::2], rotation='vertical')
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=len(x)/2)
plt.plot(x, y, 'g-', color='red')
plt.tight_layout(pad=4)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

Using `plt.locator_params` and the length of your list it could be divided in half for example:

```
plt.xticks(x, labels[::2], rotation='vertical') # set divisor
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=len(x)/2)  # set divisor
```

[image: plot 1]

This should display half the number  of ticks (`x / 2`) while keeping your plot uniform. This will work on strings and integers since the length (len) of `x` is working from a list.

```
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=len(x))
```

[image: plot 2]

If you want tighter spacing use no divisor or adjust accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I want to display the whole information but decrease the number of x.

Comment: @JoeLu: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The function I answered with will take your list `["alice", "bob", ...]` and truncate it so it's only two characters. I thought that's what you were looking to do.

Comment: @I'L'I I mean I do not want my x label to be truncated. You can see my updated question. Even if I rotate x label 90 degree it still looks uncomfortable.

Comment: @I'L'I That's great but there is one small problem. For example length of x is 6, now it displays x[0], x[1] and x[2] on x-axis, but it should display x[0], x[2] and x[4].

Comment: @JoeLu: It shouldn't, I think you might've confused this for the other answer. This method will evenly divide the ticks, so you won't encounter that issue.

Comment: @I'L'I No I have tried and it looked like what I said.

Comment: @I'L'I I have tried all you said and it really didn't work. You should try it yourself and post the result.

Answer (score 2):

If x-axis is crowded I suggest you an other solution: you can rotate x-values with `plt.xticks(rotation=45)`

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion since it's specific to `pyplot`, I might suggest `rotation='vertical'` as well. +1

Comment: @AlessandroPeca I just updated my question, it is not so good.