# Decrease index-ticks frequency

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this sample data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA': np.random.choice([False,True], 100000),
                   'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB': np.random.choice([False,True], 100000),
                   'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC': np.random.choice([False,True], 100000)},
                  index= np.random.choice([202006,202006, 202006,202005,202005,202005,202004,202004,202003], 100000)).sort_index(ascending=False)
```

With this plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
cmap = sns.mpl_palette("Set2", 2)
sns.heatmap(data=df, cmap=cmap, cbar=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=10)

legend_handles = [Patch(color=cmap[True], label='Missing Value'),  # red
                  Patch(color=cmap[False], label='Non Missing Value')]  # green
plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 1.02], loc='lower center', fontsize=8, handlelength=.8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The overlapping occurs because of the length of the variables names (I cannot change them as they are informative in my real plot). So, I need to decrease the frequency of y-ticks, it could be two ticks per value (when the month changes), or *simply?* eliminating the overlapping you see in the image above. The y-ticks of this plot needs to show clearly when the next month starts and ends (202006 means June of 2020), because with the real data I have, I can see if a whole piece of data is missing for a whole month (or more months) for any variable.

All possible-adaptable solutions I have found are based when the ticks are from a column: [Change tick frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128668/change-the-tick-frequency-when-value-of-x-axis-is-string), [adding space between ticks labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969867/how-do-i-add-space-between-the-ticklabels-and-the-axes-in-matplotlib#comment52596504_29524883), [increase spacing between ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523710/matplotlib-increase-spacing-between-points-on-x-axis), among others. but I'm still struggling with any adaptation.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: You can't increase/decrease the size of the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your DataFrame with a small correction, namely set the number
of elements as a variable (*n*):

```
n = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA': np.random.choice([False,True], n),
                   'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB': np.random.choice([False,True], n),
                   'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC': np.random.choice([False,True], n)},
    index = np.random.choice([202006,202006, 202006,202005,202005,202005,
        202004,202004,202003], n)).sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Then run your drawing code with another 2 corrections, namely:

- set `yLabelNo = 10` (the number of *y* labels),
- pass `yticklabels=n // yLabelNo` to `sns.heatmap`.

So the code is:

```py
    yLabelNo = 10
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
    cmap = sns.mpl_palette("Set2", 2)
    sns.heatmap(data=df, cmap=cmap, cbar=False, yticklabels=n // yLabelNo)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
    plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=10)
    legend_handles = [Patch(color=cmap[True], label='Missing Value'),  # red
                      Patch(color=cmap[False], label='Non Missing Value')]  # green
    plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 1.02],
        loc='lower center', fontsize=8, handlelength=.8)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

And the result is:

[image]

If you wish, experiment with other (maybe smaller) values of *yLabelNo*.

Comment: As the dataframe cannot be changed (do you think should I have specified that maybe?) I used your solution with a small workaround: `yticklabels=len(df)//yLabelNo`

Comment: Yes, in this case *n* is not needed.