# Manually change xticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to make some plot of a variable having 4 values:

```
for station in stations:
    os.chdir(inbasedir)
    nc = Dataset(surf + station + "Fluxnet.nc", 'r+')
    soil_moist = nc.variables['SoilMoist'][:,0,0]
    plt.plot(soil_moist, c='black', linewidth=0.5, label="Soil Moisture - 4 layers")
```

Which gives me the following plot:

[image]

How could I modify the xticks as follow:

- how to replace the 0 by 1, the 1 by 2, the 2 by 3 and the 3 by 4?

  - how can I remove the 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ?
  - how can I get rid of the floating point numerotation?

I tried this answer:
[Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

but it does not work and provides me the following error:
TypeError: arange: scalar arguments expected instead of a tuple.

Comment: This may help https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Make sure to plot the actual data

If 0 really denotes 1, you should plot 1 in the first place.

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [.3,.3,.25,.29]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Set the locations to integer numbers

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [.3,.3,.25,.29]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `xticks` method of `matplotlib.pyplot` expects an array for the values to display as first argument and an array with labels for those elements in the first array. So add the following to your code:

```
plt.xticks(positions, labels)
```

Where `positions` is the array of the values you want to display, and `labels` the labels you want to give to those values.