# Python MatPlotLib tick marks

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please help me figure out these tick marks.  I have been working on this for hours and I can't find a solution. This data set is a collection of average house prices for various cities, from 1996-04 to late 2018. Here is my code:

```
# Plotting Hot Springs housing value over time
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax=plt.axes
plt.plot(syrHST['71913'],color='blue')
plt.plot(syrHST['71901'],color='red')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Average Housing Value', fontsize=20)
plt.gca().legend(('71913','71901'), fontsize=20, loc='upper left')
fig.suptitle('Hot Springs', fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

Here's what it's showing me:

[image]

Obviously those tick labels along the x-axis are no good.  I need to find a way to reduce the number of labels to about 22 so they can be read clearly.  I have tried rotating the labels, but that doesn't help.  Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ticks to some output of `np.arange` using something like this:

```
def aranger(cols, n_ticks):
    return np.arange(cols.min(), cols.max(), (cols.max()-cols.min())/n_ticks)

# Plotting Hot Springs housing value over time
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax=plt.axes
index = aranger(syrHST[['71913','71901']], 10)
plt.plot(syrHST['71913'],color='blue')
plt.plot(syrHST['71901'],color='red')
plt.xticks(index, rotation='vertical', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Average Housing Value', fontsize=20)
plt.gca().legend(('71913','71901'), fontsize=20, loc='upper left')
fig.suptitle('Hot Springs', fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

Without dummy data I can't test that, but it's the general pattern I think you can use for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are strings. They are hence interpreted as categories and each category receives its own label. What you want to do is to convert them to an actual date.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

If you then plot a column from the dataframe it would show you some automatic number of dates (not more than 9 along the axis in most cases).