# How to change the ticks on x-axis?

Tags: python, plot, axis

I want change the x-axis ticks. I want: `0 10 20 30 40 50 ...`

```
    with pydicom.dcmread(directory) as dataset:
        all_population_ages.append(dataset.PatientAge)
        
plt.hist(all_population_ages,  histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100, step=10))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: image plt.hist]

I tried this solution:
[Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(all_population_ages), max(all_population_ages) + 1, 10.0))
```

But receive an error:

> plt.xticks(np.arange(min(all_population_ages), max(all_population_ages) + 1, 10.0))
>
> TypeError: must be str, not int

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: the stack trace is telling you to convert the items from int to string, i.e. `['{:d}'.format(x) for x in np.arange(0,10,1)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

```
results = list(map(int, all_population_ages))
    bins = np.arange(0, 100, 5)  # fixed bin size
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
    plt.hist(results, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, rwidth=0.8)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100, 5))
```

I changed list of string to list of int.
I changed font size.