# X axis doesn't show when plotting dataframe

Tags: python, matlab, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe with dates as index as shares as columns 
I want to plot a particular share using dates as x axis. 
The series I want to plot is :
df['APPL']=

```
Date
2018-10-29    24.903347
2018-10-30    25.165384
2018-10-31    25.087744
2018-11-01    24.777180
...
2018-12-06    25.709999
```

But when I plot it out with `df['APPL'].plot(use_index=True`), the xasix is not showing. 
Then I tried `plt.plot(df.index,df['APPL'])`, the interval of x axis is too small for it to be read.[image] .
How can I increase the interval to show every 10 days for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found to the solution, this code changes the interval to 3 days. 
Kudos to @U9-Forward and @wwii for pointing out my index was not datetime format.

```
df.index=pandas.to_datetime(df.index)
ax = df['APPL'].plot()
# set monthly locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=3))
# set formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
# set font and rotation for date tick labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

**Demo:**

```
plt.plot(df.index,df['APPL'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

After rotating, the text would be rotated to 90 degrees.

And if you prefer:

```
plt.plot(df.index,df['APPL'])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Test which you like.

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer to increase the interval to only show every 10 days for example.

Comment: @Candice You can set the number anytime, and whichever is the best for you, use it.

Comment: Hi again.. i would prefer to increase the interval then use the rotation. :) Thanks

Comment: @Candice I don't understand what you mean about that

Comment: as in reduce the frequency of x axis? instead of 
2018-10-30  
2018-10-31   
2018-11-01....  I would like to show 2018-10-30, 2018-11-01,2018-11-11 etc

Comment: @Candice [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) may help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184949/discussion-between-candice-and-u9-forward).