# Line Plot : x-axis values are not exactly same as in the data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

**I have already checked stackoverflow for any similar question but there is no answer to this.**

Recently I started learning *data visualization* in python. This is the data frame I worked upon: 
[Immigration to Canada (virtual data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0u3z.png)

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('icdf.xlsx')
df.plot(kind="line")
plt.title('Immigration to Canada (virtual data)')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Number of immigrants')
plt.show()
```

Now, on running the above code I get this plot:
[Line Plot for the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7HUz.png)

**Why does the x-axis has 9 values viz. *(1980.0, 1980.5, 1981.0, 1981.5, 1982.0,...)* whereas according to the data frame it is expected to have 5 values viz. *(1980, 1981, 1982,...)*?**

Comment: The axis values do not represent your actual data so but the looks of things you have plotted all 5 data points per line graph. you can set your ticks using `plt.xticks`

Comment: Yes, got it from the answers too. Thanks @Jetman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib). The problem seems to be just with the tick marks not the way the data is uploaded. Here are some of the best answers from that post:

> ```
> import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
>
> tick_spacing = 1
> ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
> ```

and

> ```
> plt.xticks(range(1980, 1985, 1)) #you can use min() and max()+1 to grab those from the dataframe and choose the step size according to your requirement
> ```

Comment: plt.xticks() did the trick but the code above that, was something I haven't tried yet. Will check the docs on that. Thanks.