# Plotting numbers in a file against their position in a file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a set of numbers against their position in a file.

For instance, the first few lines of the file are shown below:

```
93
90
77
79
83
96
111
115
115
118
129
138
153
147
151
164
166
162
161
157
165
148
161
161
143
```

Now, I want to plot each number against the line number in the file.

```
X axis - line number in the file
Y axis - the value of the number at that specific line
```

I wrote the following code which plots the graph for first 5000 numbers in the file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

X, Y = [], []
counter = 1

for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r'):
  X.append(float(counter))
  Y.append(float(line))
  counter = counter + 1
  if counter > 5000:
    break

plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

The graph looks like shown below:

[image]

However, I want X-Axis to show more detailed intervals and the graph should look like below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Both these duplicates are not relevant. The problem is solved here not by increasing the tick frequency but by using a bar plot with thin bar width as answered below

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

You have got it almost correct, all you need to do is change the type of graph to be used.

**Code**

```
plt.bar(X, Y, align='center', width=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Change the width according to the thickness of the bar you need.

**Resources**

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html
http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html

Comment: for this many points i would use a stem plot. additionally, using `bar` will attempt to label every single bar with its own tick. the result will not look good or even be legible.

Comment: @PaulH: Not necessarily. On my system, I get only major ticks for the example provided at intervals of 5 (0, 5, 10, 15...). Stem plot has other parameters to take care of: markers, connecting lines, base line etc.. Bar plot is rather simple

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are using `plot` (which plots arrays as continuous line) while matplotlib has other functions such as `matplotlib.pyplot.vlines` which can make your requested image .

This function spares you from making the **X** list in your example (which speed up your program) if no line is empty in your file.

Otherwise you can put zero in **Y** list if  the line is empty,
here's the [vlines docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html?highlight=vlines#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines)

I think there's no need to rewrite your program,as it is straightforward now.