# How to have fixed x ticks while plotting using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe columns are employee and X-Folder. This is the example of data:

[image]

For every unique employee I count the number of each X-Folder. In this case X-Folders are contacts, straw, conference etc. I plot graph using:
from collections import Counter

```
for e in employees:

        topics = df1.loc[df1.employee==e , "X-Folder"]

        letter_counts = Counter(topics)

        df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient='index')
        ax = df2.plot( kind='bar',figsize=(10,10))
```

It is working just fine. The only problem is that x-ticks are not fixed. For example for first employee conference, meetings , active international is zero. So, it won't show these on x axis and will only show contacts and straw. I want a graph that shows all the labels.

Edit: I want all the topics shown on x axis with only relevant counter values plotted
Edit: This is what I have done. I have stored all the topics in a list and in the dictionary letter_counts I just assign it the value zero. It works fine for the bar graph:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
topic = df1["X-Folder"].unique()

```
for e in employees:

        topics = df1.loc[df1.employee==e , "X-Folder"]

        letter_counts = Counter(topics)
        for t in topic:
            if str(t) not in letter_counts.keys():
                letter_counts[t] = 0

        df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient='index')
        ax = df2.plot( kind='bar',figsize=(20,10))
```

This is the output
[image]

But for the area graph it doesnt work (only prints 4 of the topics from a total of 23 topics):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, putting in your own values for x of course.

From [StackOverflow: Changing the “tick frequency” on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

```
x = [1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
```

Comment: I don't want numbered ticks. I wan't the actual string values of X-Folder

Comment: I believe you can just load those values into the list(x) and get your result. Have you tried that? Can you perhaps post some actual data, and the output of the chart - so we can better recreate?