# how to show over count sequential in matplotlib pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

My Code

```
over = list(range(1,21))
bangladesh = [10, 12, 15, 19, 22, 33, 40, 54, 67, 77, 89, 102, 120, 135, 155, 170, 195, 209, 220, 235]
india = [1, 6, 10, 19, 22, 31, 32, 34, 47, 54, 67, 79, 100, 125, 135, 140, 145, 157, 168, 175]

plt.plot(over, bangladesh, label='Bangladesh')
plt.plot(over, india, label='India')
plt.title('Run Overflow')
plt.xlabel('Over')
plt.ylabel('Run')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[This is my output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyg2n.png)

Here is show the over count 2.5, 5, 7.5 ...
but i want to see the over 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.....
so, how can i do this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib Is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html):

```
over = list(range(1,21))
bangladesh = [10, 12, 15, 19, 22, 33, 40, 54, 67, 77, 89, 102, 120, 135, 155, 170, 195, 209, 220, 235]
india = [1, 6, 10, 19, 22, 31, 32, 34, 47, 54, 67, 79, 100, 125, 135, 140, 145, 157, 168, 175]

plt.plot(over, bangladesh, label='Bangladesh')
plt.plot(over, india, label='India')
plt.title('Run Overflow')
plt.xlabel('Over')
plt.ylabel('Run')
plt.xticks(range(1,21))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]