# format graph of data using Pandas datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot, graph

I want to graph a pandas data frame named vslr (414 rows, 2 columns,  but the graph I am getting is unusable.

The command I am using to plot:

```
plt.plot(vslr['Price'],vslr['Date'])
```

The graph:
[image]

My data:

```
print(vslr.head)
                 Date   Price
0    2020-01-31 15:30:00  8.1653
1    2020-01-31 14:30:00  8.2087
2    2020-01-31 13:30:00  8.1753
3    2020-01-31 12:30:00  8.1551
4    2020-01-31 11:30:00  8.0903
..                   ...     ...
409  2019-11-05 13:30:00  6.8452
410  2019-11-05 12:30:00  6.8050
411  2019-11-05 11:30:00  6.7600
412  2019-11-05 10:30:00  6.7553
413  2019-11-05 09:30:00  6.6502

vslr.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 414 entries, 0 to 413
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Date     414 non-null object
Price    414 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 6.6+ KB
```

Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are getting a 'useless' graph becasue of the axis you have choosen to plot Date on, normally you would plot Date on `x-axis` and prices on `y-axis` and then check for your graph.
In [Matplotlib.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) first argument is plotted on x-axis and secon argument is plotted on y-axis

You may need to sort your dataframe by date as well in ascending order for this use:

```
vslr.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
plt.plot(vslr['Date'],vslr['Price'])
```

Note since this is a `DateTime` time column, missing dates will get their ticks as well.
Your main goal seems to be plotting over prices vs date so you can extract them from your `Date` columns as well.

```
vslr['Date']=pd.to_datetime(vslr['Date'])
vslr['Date']=vslr['date'].dt.date
```

If you set the index to the `datetime` matplotlib will handle the x axis for you. Here an example

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date_time = ["2011-09-01", "2011-08-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-05-01"]
date_time = pd.to_datetime(date_time)
temp = [2, 4, 6, 4, 6]

DF = pd.DataFrame()
DF['temp'] = temp
DF = DF.set_index(date_time)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(DF)
```

Setting the `df` index to the `datetime` series allows `matplotlib` to deal with `x-axis` on time series data, also look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib/36229671#36229671) for handling spacing on x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

As i can observe you are dealing with time series data, if you just want to plot it without some pre processing( diving it into months maybe be yearly ), follow this article [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_visualization/seaborn_pandas_timeseries_plot/).

but let us suppose you like to divide your data set into segments you could do the following using date [properties](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#datetimelike-properties) , and then plot it over that axis.

```
 vslr['date']=pd.to_datetime(vslr['date'])
 vslr['month']=vslr['date'].dt.month
 vslr.groupby('month').aggregate({'Price':'sum'}).reset_index()
```