# Change tick interval with matplotlib.figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, figure

Is there a way to change the interval for the x-value? they're pretty clumped up right now and i dont need to show everyone, i may only need to show 1 per 20.

[Pic of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirSl.png)

```
def create_window_graph(xas,yas,labname):

fig = Figure(figsize=(8, 4), dpi=80)

fig.add_subplot(111).plot(xas,yas, 'r--', label = labname) 


fig.legend()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using maptplotlib.pyplot it's pretty straightforward:

ax.set_xlim(xmin = , xmax = )

You can see the full documentation here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html

Comment: Ah yes it did work, but not quite what i thought about, since i want it to plot all the values like above in the image, but i dont want it to show the text for each value it plots on the x graph if that make sense ? Like if i have a graph that plots from 0-20 and i only want the text to show 5 10 15 20. And not every number from 1-20 in the text

Comment: If I understand you want to plot everything, but only show specific ticks?

Comment: I have the solution for your problem. Matplotlib has a built in function that does the trick:

you can select a list values that will be the ticks in the x axis:
matplotlib.pyplot.xticks( )

Full documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: You also have here a solution for a question that is the same as yours:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib