# How to modify xtick frequency for logscale?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a DataFrame by means of `DataFrame.plot()` and setting `logx=True`, the major ticks of the x-axis are spaced by a factor of 100). I would like to have them spaced by a factor of 10, i.e. 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1 etc. Is there a simple way to do it?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) is relevant I think. Just use `plt.xticks()` function

Comment: See [this doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html)  `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(base=10, numticks=15))`