# how to prevent seaborn to skip year in xtick label in Timeseries Plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have included the screenshot of the plot. Is there a way to prevent seaborn from skipping the xtick labels in timeseries data.

[image: Timeseries plot skipping the years in x axis.]

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio code is as below:   sns.lineplot(x='ReqeustYear',y='Values', data=df).

Comment: This question is already replied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most `seaborn` functions return a `matplotlib` object, so you can control the number of major ticks displayed via `matplotlib`. By default, `matplotlib` will auto-scale, which is why it hides some year labels, you can try to set the `MaxNLocator`.

Consider the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
df.drop_duplicates('year', inplace=True)
df.year = df.year.astype('str')

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2))
sns.lineplot(x='year', y='passengers', data=df, ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
```

This gives you:

[image]

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
```

will give you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answer of @steven, just want to say that methods for xticks like `plt.xticks` or `ax.xaxis.set_ticks` seem more natural to me. Full details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib?rq=1).

Comment: `plt.xticks` is a top-level function, but you need to access and control the axes return by seaborn here. `set_ticks` needs you to define tickes. So they are not really easy to use.