# Seaborn Swarmplot Axis Interval Formatting

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, swarmplot

Currently, my seaborn swarm plot has the x axis intervals too close together resulting in a plot that looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFH2p.png) Below is my current code where. Toy data x-values (32, 34, 76, 34, 64, 34, 23, 76, 34, 63, 75, 34, 76, 34, 34, 45, 56, 67, 34, 56) Y-values (0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0)

```
sns.swarmplot(x="age", y="sex", hue="target", palette=["green", "red"], data=df)
```

Is there a way to format the intervals? For instance, I would like the x-axis to have a total of 5 labels total. When I plot using relplot the axis labels look fine, but it messes up when I switch to swarmplot. I cannot seem to find info on this anywhere. All the other questions asked that I found do not seem to work on swarmplots.

This post here [(post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) is very similar to my question, however I am not using plt but instead am using seaborn. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to all matplotlib functionallity via `ax = sns.swarmplot(...)` and then call e.g. `ax.get_xticks()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(30, 80, N, dtype=int),
                   'y': np.random.randint(0, 2, N),
                   'target': np.random.randint(0, 2, N)})
ax = sns.swarmplot(x='x', y='y', hue="target", palette=["green", "red"], data=df)
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticks(ticks[4::5])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels[4::5])
ax.set_yticks([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]