# How to set X and Y intervals for matplotlib.pypplot.scatter()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have the following code for plotting two variables 'field_size' and 'field_mean_LAI':

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(df.field_size, df.field_lai_mean)
plt.title("Field Size and LAI Plot")
plt.xlabel("Field Size")
plt.ylabel("Mean LAI")
plt.show()
```

The outcome is a scatter plot:
"[image]

How can I configure the x and y intervals and change color of the plot?? I am very beginner in python plotting.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more precisely what is needed?  What do you mean by "configure the x and y intervals and change color of the plot"?

Comment: Maybe some of the 2D plots at [this seaborn tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) could be interesting?

Comment: Hi, it would be nice to have clear information about the expected output. You can change the color of the points by providing `c`or `color` within plt.scatter.  Also, formatting related question have been asked before. Here is one example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Got the solution. Posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of plot points, you can use *color* attribute (see below).

To set limits of both axes, you can pass *xlim* and *ylim* parameters
while creating the subplot.

Note also that I passed here also *rot* parameter, to set *x* labels rotation.

And to configure *x* and *y* intervals, you can use e.g. *MultipleLocator*,
for both *major* and *minor* ticks. There are other locators too,
search the Web for details.

Additional element which you can set is also the grid (like I did).

So you can change your code to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = plt.subplot(xlim=(-0.000003, 0.000123), ylim=(-0.5, 9))
df.plot.scatter(x='field_size', y='field_lai_mean', rot=30, color='r', ax=ax)
plt.title("Field Size and LAI Plot")
plt.xlabel("Field Size")
plt.ylabel("Mean LAI")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(0.4))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(0.00001))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(0.0000025))
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

Of course, adjust passed values to your needs.

For a very limited set of points, I got the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So I modified my code like below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(df.field_size, df.field_lai_mean)
plt.title("Field Size and LAI Plot")
plt.xlabel("Field Size")
plt.ylabel("Mean LAI")

plt.xticks(np.arange(0.00000,0.00013,step=0.000008))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,8.5,step=0.5))

plt.show()
```

Now I have a plot like this:

[image]

Just defined the xticks and yticks functions and it is done smoothly! :)