# Unable to change the tick frequency on my chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have seen many questions on changing the tick frequency on SO, and that did help when I am building a line chart, but I have been struggling when its a bar chart. So below are my codes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(90,1)),columns=['Values'])
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

and thats the output I see. How do I change the tick frequency ?

(To be more clearer frequency of 5 on x axis!)

[image]

Comment: to something more visible on y-axis.

Comment: added something to the original questions, hopefully should be more clearer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: you are not using Matplotlib but Pandas plot function in your example ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html )

Comment: I assume you mean the x-axis. The y-axis is fine

Comment: @SiHa unfortunately it doesnt as it works well for line plots but I am trying to create a bar plot.

Comment: and yes you are indeed right ! it is x axis!

Comment: thanks @RuthgerRighart can you modify my code and show how to get the spacing of 5 in x axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pandas plot function you can do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(90,1)),columns=['Values'])
df.plot(kind='bar', xticks=np.arange(0,90,5))
```

Or better:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', xticks=list(df.index[0::5]))
```

Comment: @user13412850: It's my pleasure!

Comment: one issue though, if I start my index from 2100, instead of 0, then I am struggling to get the spacing on my x axis, so if I just add  df.index = np.arange(2100,2190,1) to my original code. How do I get the spacing now? (btw I can create a new thread if you want me to)

Comment: created one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808294/how-do-i-change-the-frequency-while-producing-a-bar-plot