# how do I change the frequency while producing a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas

This is an addition to the original question i had asked here
[Unable to change the tick frequency on my chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807325/unable-to-change-the-tick-frequency-on-my-chart/64807568?noredirect=1#comment114583142_64807568)

The answer works absolutely fine, but when my index starts from say 2100 (instead of 0) in my original Q,the graph looks incorrect.

How do I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(90,1)),columns=['Values'])
df.index = np.arange(2100,2190,1)
df.plot(kind='bar', xticks=np.arange(2100,2190,5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With bar plots, the xticks are the range index. So you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(90,1)),columns=['Values'])
df.index = np.arange(2100,2190,1)

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,len(df),5))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index[::5]);
```

Output:

[image]