# Matplotlib: X coords won't spread out and keep clumping

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am writing a program that is analyzing data over a series of dates (the dates are my xcoords). while my y coords behave and the axis will spread out nicely, the x coords all clump up which makes it hard to read and I think also splits the two sets of data that I apply to the plot.
My x coords are a series of numbers going from 47 to 695 approximately.

```
#scatter points
        plt.scatter(dayArray1, newArray1, c='b', s = 10)
        plt.scatter(dayArray2, newArray2, c='r', s = 10)
```

[image]
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You can set the X tick interval yourself using `xticks`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you that did it.

Comment: Convert dayArray to datetime objects instead of strings.