# Change axis x scale in a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I find myself graphing by means of bars a Dataframe that I have called `barras` that contains data from 2017 to 2022, for months. In each month there are 3 columns with data denominated as `% PRINCIPAL, % APORTES y % E`. I wanted to be able to graph the bars since 2009, even if there is no data, and that only the 1st and 6th months of each month appear on the x-axis labels, but I can't do it.

This is the Dataframe:

```
% PRINCIPAL  % APORTES       % ΔE
FECHA                                     
2017-03    25.974253  42.430129  31.595618
2017-04   131.728602  27.057582 -58.786184
2017-05   144.069530  17.564611 -61.634142
2017-06   116.492102  25.948196 -42.440299
2017-07    95.677079  42.383666 -38.060745
             ...        ...        ...
2022-05    86.728444  46.208640 -32.937084
2022-06    87.980394  58.643608 -46.624002
2022-07    73.873644  53.591839 -27.465483
2022-08    72.113597  44.375137 -16.488734
2022-09    52.777619  79.301887 -32.079506
```

And this is my code to do the graphic:

```
barras = pd.concat([I['% PRINCIPAL'],I['% APORTES'],I['% ΔE']], axis=1)
barras.index = pd.to_datetime(barras.index).strftime('%Y-%m')
barras.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True, color = ['b','g','r'], edgecolor='black', width=1, alpha=0.77, figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('PORCENTAJES DE CAUDAL EN TRAMO I')
plt.ylabel("Caudal (%)")
plt.xlabel('Fecha')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig("BLOQUE I.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=160)
```

Result:

[image]

I want the same graphic but since 2009, and with the x-axis label each six moths.

I would like to get something like this (I've done it with photoshop):

[image]

Comment: Do you want to bin your data? [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: No, I only want to see the graphic since 2009, although I know that there are not data from 2009 to 2017. And in the other hand I would like to see only the label each six month, not all label that are so much, and since 2009 it label will be so small.

Comment: For the number labels maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-the-x-or-y-axis) helps, for the range try [`xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

Comment: It seems usefull but i can't do it, i don't now the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate your dataframe with another one containing the rest of the dates you are interested in and then plot that.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create dummy data 
dates = pd.date_range('2/2017', '8/2022', freq='M')
values = np.random.uniform(-100, 100, (len(dates), 3))
barras = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['% PRINCIPAL',  '% APORTES', '% ΔE'], index=dates)

# Create new dataframe with 0s for dates starting from 2009
add_dates = pd.date_range('1/2009', barras.index[0], freq='M')[:-1]
df_0 = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['% PRINCIPAL',  '% APORTES', '% ΔE'], index=add_dates)

# Concatenate everything into a single dataframe
barras = pd.concat([df_0, barras])

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,8))
barras.set_index(barras.index.strftime('%Y-%m')).plot(
    kind="bar",
    stacked=True,
    color = ['b','g','r'],
    edgecolor='black',
    width=1,
    alpha=0.77,
    ax=ax
    )

new_ticks = ax.get_xticks()[barras.index.month.isin([1,1+6])]
ax.set_xticks(new_ticks)

plt.title('PORCENTAJES DE CAUDAL EN TRAMO I')
plt.ylabel("Caudal (%)")
plt.xlabel('Fecha')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig("BLOQUE I.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=160)
```

EDIT: Now the code shows all the data and the temporal line is right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks u very much! Its works! But I only have one question, and is that the frequency of data show is six moths, bur i want to plot all data, but only show the label each six moth...  I think that I did not explain good in the post. Thanks you again!

Comment: And the x-axis label of your graphic is wrong, it good that show every six months, but the temporal line don't follow a logical orden...

Comment: I fixed the x axis in the code so plot equally spaced dates and also it is plotting all the data now.