# Non-overlapping numbers on plot axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make the numbers on my y axis not over lap with each other as shown in the image below. I have my code using matplotlib to plot all 8 plots at time using the plt.tight_layout() command. I am not sure what is the best way to fix the overlapping seen in the bottom four plots.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
a1 = fig.add_subplot(421)
a2 = fig.add_subplot(422)
a3 = fig.add_subplot(423)
a4 = fig.add_subplot(424)
a5 = fig.add_subplot(425)
a6 = fig.add_subplot(426)
a7 = fig.add_subplot(427)
a8 = fig.add_subplot(428)

a1.plot(Msol, ilP, color='blue')
a1.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a1.set_ylabel(r'$Log Pressure$')

a2.plot(Msol, ilT, color='blue')
a2.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a2.set_ylabel(r'$Log Temperature$')

a3.plot(Msol, ilRho, color='blue')
a3.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a3.set_ylabel(r'$Log Density$')

a4.plot(Msol, Rsol, color='blue')
a4.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a4.set_ylabel(r'$R/R\odot$')

a5.plot(Msol, Lsol, color='blue')
a5.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a5.set_ylabel(r'$L/L\odot$')

a6.plot(Msol, iK, color='blue')
a6.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a6.set_ylabel(r'$Opacity$')

a7.plot(Msol, ieg, color='blue')
a7.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a7.set_ylabel(r'$\epsilon$')

a8.plot(Msol, ir_c, color='blue')
a8.set_xlabel(r'$M/M\odot$')
a8.set_ylabel(r'$Convective Ratio$')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `get_ylim`, `set_yticks` and possibly `set_fontsize`

```
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot( np.random.randn( 1000 ).cumsum( ) )

lb, ub = ax.get_ylim( )
ax.set_yticks( np.linspace(lb, ub, 25 ) )

for x in ax.get_yticklabels( ):
    x.set_fontsize( 'small' )
```

[image: tight]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html), `tight_layout` works only on position and padding of the graphs, and not on the ticks range and number. As you know that your graphs will be small, maybe you should [adjust the number of ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/how-to-reduce-number-of-ticks-with-matplotlib) on your own?