# Python matplotlib: fractional logscale

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to plot some data with a fractional logscale, such that the y axis has the ticks at 10^(-0.1), 10^(-0.2), 10^(-0.3), etc. 
The problem is that when I plot my data, there are only ticks at 10^0 and 10^-1, which leaves the slope of the line too slight to see.

Is is possible to set a fractional logscale this way?

Thanks

Comment: Related questions that may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/how-to-reduce-number-of-ticks-with-matplotlib and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks, I had a look but still couldn't figure out to do it. I tried this: `ax.YAxis.set_ticks([10**0,10**(-0.1),10**(-0.2),10**(-0.3)])` but that didn't work. I'm new to matplotlib

Comment: Did you try any of the other suggestions at the linked pages? Also, it should be `ax.yaxis`; `ax.YAxis` doesn't even exist (though perhaps it did in an old matplotlib version).

Comment: Or you may simply want to scale the y-axis: `ax.set_ylim(1e-3, 1)`.

Comment: How do you use `ax.set_ylim`? It says `invalid syntax` when I try to use it.

Comment: This is what I've tried: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; fig, ax = plt.subplots(); plt.plot(X,Y); plt.yscale('log'); ax.set_yticks([10**0,10**(-0.1),10**(-0.2),10**(-0.3)])`. But that just adds extra ticks. I need to rescale the plot

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want tick *labels*, not the tick *marks* in particular. In most figures, the minor tick marks are already there where you want them.

The following may then work, though I would think there's an easier way. Note that I'm applying labels to the minor tick marks only: the (two) major tick marks already have a label. Unfortunately, the fonts of the two types of tick marks are not the same; I think that's a result of the LaTeX equation usage.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X = np.logspace(0, 3)
Y = X**-0.2
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.yscale('log')
yticks = np.linspace(-0.1, -0.9, 9)
ax.set_yticks(10**yticks, minor=True)
ax.set_ylim(0.1, 1)
ax.set_yticklabels(['$10^{{{:.1f}}}$'.format(ytick) for ytick in yticks], minor=True)
plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

For the issue of the different label fonts, you can manually change the major tick labels:

```
ax.set_yticks([1, 0.1])
ax.set_yticklabels(['$10^0$', '$10^{-1}$'])
```

(and probably the same for the x-axis).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this for now. If no one else can think of an automatic way to do it, then I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: By the way, it should be 9 ticks, not 10, in `yticks = np.linspace(-0.1, -0.9, 9)`. I couldn't edit your submission because at least 6 characters must be changed for a valid edit.

Comment: `10^-0.5` appears twice

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Looks like matplotlib rounds those ticks, so with the ten ticks across the interval at [-0.1, -0.1888, -0.2777, -0.3666, -0.4555, -0.5444, ..., -0.9], those got rounded to [-0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.5, -0.5, .... -0.9]. Corrected now.