# Python:How to change the granularity of axes in matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am wondering how to can change the number of bins in a line plot in matplotlin python pandas?
like if my x axis range is [0,1000] and I want it be decided to 200 ticks. Can anybody help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/how-to-reduce-number-of-ticks-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 3):

Use the set_ticks function

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks([0,200,400,800,1000])
```