# Matplotlib: Set minimum number of ticks when specifying locator_params

Tags: matplotlib

So it is possible to specify the maximum number of ticks (or bins) easily with [locator_params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/how-to-reduce-number-of-ticks-with-matplotlib).  I am producing thousands of graphs from different data sources and need a way to also control the minimum number of bins used by the auto tick locator.

Comment: Give us a (minimal) code sample generating a plot where it generates fewer bins than you want and you can't specify more.