# Matplotlib adding too many labels to bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having a slightly frustrating situation with pandas/matplotlib (not sure which one's at fault here). If I create a simple random series and plot it as a line chart, the formatting is pretty clean:

```
test1 = pd.Series(index = pd.date_range(start='2000-06-30', end='2018-06-30', freq='3M'),
                 data = np.random.rand(73))
test1.plot(kind='line')
```

[image]

Most satisfactory. 
If I change the format to bar, though, the x-axis formatting goes to hell in a handbasket:

[image]

Matplotlib seems to feel obliged to label every single bar. Is there a logical reason for this or an easy fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By plotting as bars, you're changing a continuous variable (time) to a discrete variable.  Matplotlib is just doing what you asked it to do, which is to represent each time unit as its own bar - it's no longer a continuum, as far as the graph is concerned, so it doesn't have any intuition for how to summarize the span of the x axis (since there's no span, just categories now).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714879/2799941) for your solution.  Just set `ax = test1.plot(kind='bar')` to make the answer work in your case.

Comment: @andrew_reece: Thanks - that does give some clarification on its behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib is trying to use each time as its own bar, and is trying to label each bar appropriately. To change this behaviour, you should change the `xticks` or the `xticklabels`. For example, one quick way to just remove the labels entirely is to do something like

```
subplot = test1.plot(kind='bar')
ax = subplot.axes
#ax.set_xticks([])       # Alternatively, you can manually adjust the ticks
ax.set_xticklabels([])   # or their labels
f = ax.get_figure()
f.show()
```

which will produce

[image: A plot with no tick labels]

You can reduce the number of ticks to something like using every `n`th tick and its label in the same way.