# Change number of ticks on a AxisArtist

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, axis-labels

I am trying to plot cartesian axes like [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axisline_style.html):

[image]

Because of overlapping yticks I want to reduce their number. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714879/5537840) approach.

```
for n, label in enumerate(ax.axis[direction].get_ticklabels()):
    if n % 5 != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

But it gave an error:

```
'AxisArtist' object has no attribute 'get_ticklabels'
```

How can I overcome it?

Comment: In general, check the examples from the current version, rather than old ones. E.g. [the spine placement](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html), or [axisline style](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html). For ticking, consider using locators as in [tick-locators](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html), e.g. a `MultipleLocator` or a `MaxNLocator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines` is deprecated; import from `mpl_toolkits.axisartist` instead.

Adding `ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5))` will do.

If you want to dynamically space out ticks depending on axis extents, you can use `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(*ax.axis()[2:], 0.5))` (to set distance between ticks) or `ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(*ax.axis()[2:], 5))` (to set number of ticks).

Example result:

[image: Example result]