# How to show all the labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to display a chart using matplotlib. But my labels are so big that they are overlapping each other. I want to show it cleanly no overlapping. How can I do that? I am now using below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['jdwdw723@gmail.com' ,'emcast.test10@gmail.com', 'pbChinaTester@clp.com']
y = [10,25,6]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.xlabel("loginId")
plt.ylabel("times appeared in the data")

plt.title("loginId Graph")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could rotate the labels by 90 degrees? `plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example code, and it doesn't seem to be overlapping there. There are many possibilities. One, commonly used, is to rotate the labels.

You can do it like this:

```py
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

There are more ideas in [Changing the “tick frequency” on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) and in [reducing number of plot ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/reducing-number-of-plot-ticks).

I created [an example notebook here](https://deepnote.com/project/b7f5082f-df80-475a-a567-038ad1a6998f#%2Fnotebook.ipynb), feel free to duplicate and play with it.