# Too many xticks in the histogam

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to read data from a txt file containing 200 values and then trying to plot a histogram based on the data. However, there are too many values on the `xticks`, and I do not know how to fix this.
My code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=open('LedData.rtf',"r")
lines=f.readlines()
result=[]
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split(',')[1])
f.close()

plt.hist(result)
plt.xticks(rotation = 'vertical')
plt.show
```

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhXCv.png) : Here is an image for reference.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You said txt file but you are opening a rtf file!

Comment: Yes, @raspiduino is right. How could you do that? Either way, [here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418954/9997212) for your problem.